# get post id using the $query_vars variable

Tags: query

How can I get the ID of a post (or page) based on the $query_vars variable? I want to do something like

```
$query_vars['post_id']
```

But I don't have a reference page that has the list of $query_vars perams. The code will be using the template_redirect action hook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When viewing a single post, `get_the_ID();` used within the loop will return the current post's ID.

> But I don't have a reference page that has the list of $query_vars params...

Dumping it

```
global $wp_query;
var_dump($wp_query->query_vars);
```

would provide such a reference.

Where you'd subsequently see that `$wp_query->query_vars['page_id']` yields the page ID.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on a single post or page view, try using `get_queried_object_id()`.

Or, if you don't know what type of view you're on, use `get_queried_object()` and then analyse the object returned to find out whether its a post, a taxonomy term, or something different.